# How to connect the stuntman stun server with JSTUN stun client

Tags: java, eclipse, server, client, stun

I'm just using the stuntman stun server and I want to connect the jstun client library.And I use Eclipse IDE for jstun. Now I want to connect the client and server.

Please anyone help me!

I'm trying to run jstun project by run the command in

```
mvn java -cp jstun-0.7.4.jar:slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:slf4j-jdk14-1.7.5.jar de.javawi.jstun.test.demo.DiscoveryTestDemo
```

But it shows the error of

```
Error resolving version for plugin 'jstun-0.7.4.jar:slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar'
 from the repositories [local (C:\Users\DELL\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository ->
```

I tried many ways.But it didn't works.
And I also step by step procedure to connect the jstun client with stuntman server.

Please answer me as soon as possible.

Comment: I am the maintainer and original author of Stuntman. I know for a fact that JSTUN and Stuntman interop just fine. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: I edited your original question to include your commentary you had added as an answer.  You should delete your answer below and focus on making the most understood question in the original post.

Comment: Also, I'm not a Java build expert. The JSTUN's author doesn't have great build instructions. And the last time I built it was years ago - slogging through and learning the java build process as I went.